# Increase (not decrease) row height in a Sharepoint list

Tags: json, sharepoint, row-height

I have a sharepoint list I made to track activity on a specific ticket. The main issue is that I actually want the row to show all the comments written into a multi-line text field. It is always compressing it to only show about 6 lines unless we click to edit the row. A ticket could have anywhere from 5 to 50 lines of text or more in the comments, and the purpose of this list is that others can go to the page and quickly see all the history of all the tickets by just scrolling down the page. I see a lot of people online ask how to make list rows uniform, but I have not found anyone showing how to make the rows expand to the contents. I did find one set of instructions on the JSON to input to make a row a specific height, but then larger will still be cut off unless I keep making every one set to largest--which would make some have huge amounts of white space. Does anyone know a way to just make a row fit the contents without it being in edit/grid view?

I found this, but it only sets the height to an exact amount; it doesn't make the row fit to whatever value the largest item needs.

```
{
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "width": "500px",
        "height": "100px"
      }
    }
```

The solution does not have to be JSON if there is a simpler setting.

Comment: Looks like [someone asked Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/row-height-on-list-sharepoint-online/m-p/198154) about this capability 5 years ago, said that it was not possible at the time. Unfortunately, it's not clear (to me) if the capability might now be possible since then? Perhaps someone else that crosses this question may know.

Comment: Yeah, I did not see it as a regular setting available in Sharepoint, but I am relatively new at lists . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found an answer:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "height": "auto"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, applying JSON formatting can increase the row size. As a reminder, this only works with "plain text" instead in column settings.